# Specify the next line in a regex

Tags: regex

So I am trying to replace a simple string

```
\r\n
Fixed all files in 0.001 seconds, 2.000 MB memory used\r\n
```

Up to now I have the following:

```
Fixed all files in (.*?), (.*?) memory used\\r\\n
```

But no matter how or what I try, I can't specify the first line's \r\n What am I missing?

Comment: Are those literal backslashes and `r`s and `n`s on the line above, or is that carriage return / line feed? What environment? What's the expected output, the empty string?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to replace in the string?

Comment: I'm trying the replace the whole string with nothing ''

Comment: Literal backslashes, that's the exact string I'm trying to match

Answer (score 1):

Match the first line's `\r\n` by escaping the backslashes, just like you're doing after `memory used`, then match newline character/s with `\s`, followed by your original RE:

```
\\r\\n\s+Fixed all files in (.*?), (.*?) memory used\\r\\n
```

Replace with nothing, and the result is the empty string:

https://regex101.com/r/9uWQDp/2